# Adding Images (Fixed Position) to Google Apps Documents by Script

Tags: google-apps-script

While we can add Inline Images in paragraphs there does not appear to be a way of adding images that are "fixed position" with Google Apps Script. How do I insert or manipulate fixed position images?

Comment: have you tried to analyze it in the reverse way, ie tried to get element attributes, parameters and position on an existing document with a fixed image in it ? Could be interesting couldn't it ?

Comment: Yes I did try that :) created a doc with 2 paragraphs of text. The first para had an inline image, the second para was followed by an image (fixed position)
Examinining the doc, showed two top level elements of type paragraph, the first para had 3 elements (2 text and 1 inlineimage) the secnd para had 1 text element. No sign of an element for fixed image.

Comment: I did the test too and was surprised to find nothing... my doc has only a fixed image... so I didn't continue further, I thought I was missing something in the process :-/ . I'm kind of happy you come to this result... well happy and unhappy ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentApp currently only supports the ability to return and create inline images. If you would like to see access to fixed position images you can file a feature request on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Done that but, in general, **all** document components should be available to the script.