# Manipulate PositionedImage and wrap text around image in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I used the [following snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18859986/1536038) to insert an image into a Google Document:

```
// Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18859986/1536038
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('Google Drive Id');
var img = DriveApp.getFileById('Google Drive Id').getBlob(); 
doc.getBody().insertImage(0, img);
```

The result is an `In line` image:
[image]

I want, however, to have a `Wrap text` image, like so:
[image]

Is that possible via Google Apps Script (on the fly)?

Comment: A [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575863/how-do-i-format-text-i-am-copying-from-google-document-in-google-app-script/17577431#17577431) involved copying attributes of inline images when merging documents. I figured that technique would help here, but was surprised when I tried it. Each inline image is a child of a paragraph element. Once you change an inline image to "Wrap Text", it disappears as a child of the containing paragraph! That looks like a bug; I suspect that they've introduced a new Element type, but it's not yet supported in the API.

Comment: @Mogsdad Is there perhaps a way to replace an image (that is set to wrap text)?

Comment: I don't see any method in the API that would do that - it would be nice to have something analogous to replaceText(); and it's further complicated by the fact that we can't get a handle on the object to invoke any methods anyway (see my previous comment).

Comment: I remember having seen somewhere that inline image was the only supported mode but the problem is that I can't remember where and when I saw it... (I know, this kind of info is really useless :-) ) I searched the issue tracker without success and I'm afraid it was on the old Google group discussion group that has recently been wiped out :-(  Let's hope someone from the GAS team will give a definitive answer to this.

Comment: Yes only inline images (issue 1529)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183518/adding-images-fixed-position-to-google-apps-documents-by-script

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Issue 1529](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1529) has been fixed. As of December 2015, Google Apps Script can manipulate [`PositionedImage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image.html) objects in Google Docs.

---

They behave a little differently than [`InlineImage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image) elements, as they need to be anchored to a ListItem or Paragraph element, while `InlineImages` can be added only to `Body`, `FooterSection`, `HeaderSection` or `TableCell` elements.

A `PositionedImage` is an object anchored in an element, while an `InlineImage` is itself an element of a document. *This implies that you cannot convert one type of image directly to the other.* (When you switch an image from "Wrap text" to "Inline" using the UI, the `PositionedImage` is removed from its anchor paragraph, then inserted into the body of the document outside of that paragraph. You could emulate that via script if necessary.)

#### Insert a `PositionedImage`

Here's an example of a `PositionedImage` inserted by the following script:

[image: Screenshot]

```js
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/20661113/1677912
function DemoPositionedImage() {
  // Get handle on active document
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  // Find desired image file
  var matchedFiles = DriveApp.getFilesByName('apple-touch-icon.png');
  if (matchedFiles.hasNext()) {
    // Get image object from file
    var image = matchedFiles.next().getBlob(); 

    // Add image as a PositionedImage.
    var positionedImage = doc.getBody().getParagraphs()[0].addPositionedImage(image);

    // Adjust layout, etc. here

    // Log the ID of the new image
    Logger.log( positionedImage.getId() );
  }
}
```

The log shows the ID of the new image, like this:

```js
[15-12-11 20:35:03:706 EST] kix.9dwnzjfapdy8
```

Be careful - if you add multiple images to the same element (e.g. Paragraph), with default layout, *the newest image will overlay existing ones*. Therefore, it may look like you have a single image when there are actually a pile of them.

#### Retrieve existing `PositionedImage`s

Since a `PositionedImage` is not an element of a document, it does not appear in the element hierarchy with elements like paragraphs, tables, or InlineImages, and cannot be found through the document methods `getChild()`, `getNextSibling()`, and so on. Likewise, there is no `Body.getPositionedImages()` to parallel `Body.getImages()`.

Instead, you can get a `PositionedImage` using its unique ID, e.g. `kix.9dwnzjfapdy8` from the earlier example.

```js
var positionedImage = getPositionedImage(storedId);
```

Alternatively, you can get all the `PositionedImage` objects in a containing element as an array.

```js
var positionedImages = getPositionedImages();
for (var i=0; i<positionedImages.length; i++) {
  Logger.log( positionedImages[i].getId() );
}
```

Retrieving all the `PositionedImage`s in a document requires traversing all the possible anchor elements. The following utility does just that.

```js
/**
 * Get a list of all PositionedImages in a document.
 * See stackoverflow.com/a/20661113/1677912.
 *
 * @param {String} docId         (optional) ID of document to scan
 *
 * @returns {PositionedImage[]}  Array of PositionedImages in document
 */
function getAllPositionedImages( docId ) {
  // Open document if given ID, otherwise use active document.
  if (docId) {
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  }
  else {
    doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  }

  // Get handle on document's body
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // array to hold all images in document
  var allPositionedImages = [];

  var numElems = body.getNumChildren();

  for (var childIndex=0; childIndex<numElems; childIndex++) {
    var child = body.getChild(childIndex);
    switch ( child.getType() ) {
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
        var container = child.asParagraph();
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM:
        container = child.asListItem();
        break;

      default:
        // Skip elements that can't contain PositionedImages.
        continue;
    }
    // Collect images from current container
    var imagesHere = container.getPositionedImages();
    allPositionedImages = allPositionedImages.concat(imagesHere);        
  }
  return allPositionedImages;
}
```

#### Layout control

Most of the layout controls for `PositionedImages` are well described in the documentation:

- Height: [`setHeight()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#setheightheight), [`getHeight()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#getheight)
- Width: [`setWidth()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#setwidthwidth), [`getWidth()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#getwidth)
- LeftOffset: [`setLeftOffset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#setleftoffsetoffset), [`getLeftOffset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#getleftoffset)
- TopOffset: [`setTopOffset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#settopoffsetoffset), [`getTopOffset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#gettopoffset)
- Layout: [`setLayout()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#setlayoutlayout), [`getLayout()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#getlayout)

The [`PositionedLayout` enum](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-layout) used with the **Layout** methods is unique to `PositionedImages`. At the time of launch of PositionedImage support however, it was not included in editor autocompletion, and the documentation contained no examples of its use. Let's fill that gap.

Here's how you can [set the layout](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image#setlayoutlayout) of a `PositionedImage` so that it is wrapped by text:

```js
positionedImage.setLayout( DocumentApp.PositionedLayout.WRAP_TEXT );
```

The following utility function gets the English equivalent of a `PositionedLayout` enum.

```js
/**
 * Get the string representing the given PositionedLayout enum.
 * Ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-layout
 *
 * See stackoverflow.com/a/20661113/1677912.
 *
 * @param {PositionedLayout} PositionedLayout  Enum value.
 *
 * @returns {String}         English text matching enum.
 */
function getLayoutString( PositionedLayout ) {
  var layout;
  switch ( PositionedLayout ) {
    case DocumentApp.PositionedLayout.ABOVE_TEXT:
      layout = "ABOVE_TEXT";
      break;
    case DocumentApp.PositionedLayout.BREAK_BOTH:
      layout = "BREAK_BOTH";
      break;
    case DocumentApp.PositionedLayout.BREAK_LEFT:
      layout = "BREAK_LEFT";
      break;
    case DocumentApp.PositionedLayout.BREAK_RIGHT:
      layout = "BREAK_RIGHT";
      break;
    case DocumentApp.PositionedLayout.WRAP_TEXT:
      layout = "WRAP_TEXT";
      break;
    default:
      layout = "";
      break;
  }
  return layout;
}
```

**Note:** This has been concurrently posted [on my blog](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/12/12/positionedimage-support-introduced-in-google-apps-script/).

Comment: Apps Script has added support for fixed images via the new PositionedImage class:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image

Comment: @RyanRoth How does that look now?

Comment: Thanks, Jacob! That was a nice Christmas surprise!

Comment: Looks good, Mogsdad!  Note that the issue with PositionedLayout not being included in the editor autocomplete should be corrected soon.